# Unable to connect Dataform to Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, dataform, google-cloud-source-repos

I tried the following example usage to create Dataform resources with terraform provided in [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataform_repository):

```
resource "google_sourcerepo_repository" "git_repository" {
  provider = google-beta
  name = "my/repository"
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "secret" {
  provider = google-beta
  secret_id = "secret"

  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
  provider = google-beta
  secret = google_secret_manager_secret.secret.id

  secret_data = "secret-data"
}

resource "google_dataform_repository" "dataform_respository" {
  provider = google-beta
  name = "dataform_repository"

  git_remote_settings {
      url = google_sourcerepo_repository.git_repository.url
      default_branch = "main"
      authentication_token_secret_version = google_secret_manager_secret_version.secret_version.id
  }

  workspace_compilation_overrides {
    default_database = "database"
    schema_suffix = "_suffix"
    table_prefix = "prefix_"
  }
}
```

It seems that Google Cloud Source Repositories doesn't work with this implementation due to its lack of token generation.
How can I connect my Google Cloud Source Repository to a newly created Dataform Repository?
Is Github\Gitlab\Bitbucket mandatory in order to link git with dataform?
Do you have any alternative solutions to solve this issue?

Regards,

Comment: Have you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository#create-secret)